# How to resolve circular dependency of nested type in C++?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

For code like:

```
// with forward declaration: error C2653: 'B': is not a class or namespace name
// without forward declaration: error C2027: use of undefined type 'B'
struct B;

struct A {
    using size_t = int;
    typename B::size_t index;
};

struct B {
    using size_t = char;
    typename A::size_t index;
};

void main() {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Class A and B reference nested types `size_t` of each other.

But the forward declarations like `class A;` only works for classes declared in current scope or outer scope.

So how do you resolve this circular dependency **without changing the semantics of code**? Just like solving the easier case with forward declaration, or like java and c# which do not get any kind of circular dependency problem?

---

P.S.

Thankes to Galik's suggestions, the original example in this question

> ```
> template <typename T>
> class A {
>     using iterator = T*;
>     B<T>::iterator iter;
> };
>
> template <typename T>
> class B {
>     using iterator = T*;
>     A<T>::iterator iter;
> };
> ```

contains other bugs like the `iterator` is inaccessible for they are private, and the `typename` is required before `A<T>::iterator`.
And after the bug fix, it will be compiled successfully. It seems there are some differences between generic class and normal class, so I gave an example (of normal class) at the beginning and it can not be compile in Visual Studio 2015 at least.

Comment: Use a traits class outside of `A` that defines its iterator type, and ditto for `B`.

Comment: When the iterator types are as simple as `T*`, then just use `T*` directly. You also need to fix the accessibility. And an iterator as a data member smells wrong, just as the circular dependency.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry for the bugs, I updated the example. But iterator is just a 'fancy pointer', so I think it is possible to make it a data member.

Comment: In the first code you cannot use `B::size_t` until `B` is defined , you'd have to factor out to a common third class or namespace

Comment: Can you please clarify which code sample you are really asking about? These should be two different questions , maybe you do not appreciate that the difference between `B::size_t` and `B<T>::iterator` is important, an answer for the `B::size_t` example will not be applicable to the iterator example

Comment: @M.M The former example. It seems that the compiler behaves better when handling template, so after bug fix, the later example will pass the build... But the former example will fail.

Comment: OK, I would suggest reverting your edit and posting a new question, since there is already an answer posted that answers the iterator example

Comment: @M.M I found that there are already a lot of forward declaration questions, and the old question seems to be a duplication.

Comment: that's fine but you still should not change the question so much , make a new one instead

Comment: @M.M Thanks for your suggestion, I will think and test carefully then post a question next time!

Comment: Calling a self-defined type `size_t` a) violates the reserved name rules, b) feels really wrong because `size_t` is already defined by the standard, and c) feels really wrong because you are typedefing it to small types like `char`. If I would read your code, I would never assume `size_t` to be anything other than the type defined by the standard, and I would always assume that it's capable to address any amount of memory on the system. Assumptions that your definitions violate. Please don't do this.

Comment: @cmaster Maybe I should name them a,b,c,d so you won't think this example is the whole usage of this code structure. And there may be some conditions that you need to rewrite STL for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You need `typename` before `B<T>::Iterator`, because `B<T>` is a dependent scope.

```
#include <string>
template<class T> class B;

template<class T>
class A {
public:
    using Iterator = T*;
private:
    typename B<T>::Iterator iter;
};

template<class T>
class B {
public:
    using Iterator = T*;
private:
    typename A<T>::Iterator iter;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<std::string> b;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to instantiate the classes and compile this.

Comment: @Galik, you are right. To instantiate the classes, we need Public `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the question for which the OP wants an answer.
Moreover, the example in the question contains several errors.

That said, this would solve maybe.

You can introduce a base class for one of the two classes:

```
struct A_b {
    using size_t = int;
};

struct B {
    using size_t = char;
    A_b::size_t index;
};

struct A: A_b {
    B::size_t index;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Or turn one of them to a template class:

```
template<class T>
struct A_t {
    using size_t = int;
    typename T::size_t index;
};

struct B {
    using size_t = char;
    typename A_t<B>::size_t index;
};

using A = A_t<B>;

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

And so on......

Comment: If A and B are two independent concept, this code may be very confusing. I just want to know is it possible to write code like java or c# with any kind of circular dependency without changing the semantics of code.